# Is anonymous login in XMPP a breach of Security

Tags: security, xmpp

I have been using an xmpp server that uses anonymous login.

1. Is nt anolnymous login itself a breach of security? Is it not possible that an attacker can gain access to the server and if not anything else bombard the server with huge no. of sessions which can ultimately bring it down.
2. If so then why is the concept of anonymous login is still used in xmpp.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you define "breach of security". First, in this discussion there is no difference between open registration and anonymous login enabled XMPP services. But provide potential malicious users a chance to monopolize the XMPP service so that its service quality is decreased (or the service is not available to other users at all). It is up to the server implementation to counter such attempts and to provide a reliable service, e.g., even if someone "floods" the XMPP service with stanza.

You may also want to distinguish if such a service is freely accessible, i.e. everyone can connect to it, or the service is only available to a selected group of people, e.g. within a corporate network.

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to add an authentication step and considering the below options.1 add an authentication step during the anonymous login. But this would mean my server will no more be implementing pure xmpp standard. 2 Add a cookie check, but this cannot be used for non web clients. Does these look like good approaches.

Answer (score 0):

> Is not anonymous login itself a breach of security? Is it not possible that an attacker can gain access to the server

`Answer to your both questions 1 and 2`. No, it is not a breach - anonymity is one of the nice optional services of user privacy in the cyber world. It is not a breach to security, unless cannot track down and punish an anonymous bad user who did wrong things with your system; you would not be responsible for that. Anonymity does not empower an attacker to do a [denial-of-service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) or other attacks to the server. An attacker attacks in smart ways to make himself anonymous anyway, `you must not use this as an excuse to incur a cost on all users by taking away the chance of anonymity`. So, the answer to your first question is that offering anonymity does not adversely affect the service at all.

If I have to choose an IM application, I prefer chosing one that allows me to be anonymous, and be able to chat really privately in that the admins (and therefore the government) cannot read my *private messages*. In the case of Instant Messaging applications, you must really understand the users' privacy concerns and needs.

You want to work with XMPP, it is worth taking a look at **[this awesome Off-the-Record messsaging (OTR)](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/)** protocol that works perfect with XMPP, and allows users (and not you as an admin) to further authenticate one another and be able to send messages privately such that you as an admin cannot read. There is a lot of beauty in this cryptographic extension developed by University of Waterloo's research group. The nice thing is that you as the XMPP server provider do not need to do anything to support OTR; it is already available in many platforms. OTR works seemlessly through all XMPP nodes and servers. [This](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android) is a sample project android XMPP client app that has integrated OTR. And [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) is a sample XMPP IM server that unknowingly allows OTR extension work. All IM servers should allow OTR messages I think.

---

**Further suggestion**: Privacy is not a toy to play with. We developers are really responsible for providing privacy-friendly solutions. We have to know what cause Julian Assange is suffering for now, what is [Cypherpunks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypherpunk) movement that brought about the [TOR network](https://www.torproject.org/), the OTR for IM applications, and many other ongoing projects.

These are the security services provided by OTR available on XMPP:

**Encryption** - No one else can read your instant messages.

**Authentication** - You are assured the correspondent is who you think it is.

**Deniability** - The messages you send do not have digital signatures that are checkable by a third party. Anyone can forge messages after a conversation to make them look like they came from you. However, during a conversation, your correspondent is assured the messages he sees are authentic and unmodified.

**Perfect forward secrecy** - If you lose control of your private keys, no previous conversation is compromised.
and many other awesome projects that is worthy of a minute of silence. They advocate the idea that citizens must be able to have private data communications.

These are the security services provided by OTR available on XMPP:

**Encryption** - No one else can read your instant messages.

**Authentication** - You are assured the correspondent is who you think it is.

**Deniability** - The messages you send do not have digital signatures that are checkable by a third party. Anyone can forge messages after a conversation to make them look like they came from you. However, during a conversation, your correspondent is assured the messages he sees are authentic and unmodified.

**Perfect forward secrecy** - If you lose control of your private keys, no previous conversation is compromised.